# Self as argument type of generic callback

Tags: swift, callback, associated-types

I'm trying to implement generic broadcasting function for each type that supports specific protocol. For example:

```
protocol Proto {
    typealias ItemType
    typealias Callback = (Self, ItemType)

    func register(tag: String, cb: Callback)
    func unregister(tag: String)
}

class Foo : Proto {
    typealias ItemType = Int

    func register(tag: String, cb: (Foo, Int)) {

    }

    func unregister(tag: String) {

    }
}

func bc <T: Proto> (p: T, value: T.ItemType, os: [String: T.Callback]) {
    for (k, v) in os {
        v(p, value) // error: cannot invoke v with argument list of...
    }
}
```

Question is how to implement `bc` function right?

Comment: Are you trying to invoke the initialiser of  `T.Callback`?

Comment: No, just a closure. `v` is a reference to a closure, added in Foo.register, for example. Goal is to call each registered callback with same arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think swift is buggy at this place. maybe you can use

```
protocol Proto {
    typealias ItemType

    func register(tag: String, cb: (Self, Self.ItemType)->())
    func unregister(tag: String, cb: (Self, Self.ItemType)->())
}

class Foo : Proto {

    func register(tag: String, cb: (Foo, Int)->()) {

    }
    func unregister(tag: String, cb: (Foo, Int)->()) {

    }
}

func bc <T: Proto> (p: T, value: T.ItemType, os: [String : (T,T.ItemType)->()]) {
    for (_, vc) in os {
        vc(p, value) // error: cannot invoke v with argument list of...
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks for workaround. Main drawback is what it makes you copy-past type definition.